# What's the difference between Apple Watch and Apple Watch Sport?

Tags: apple-watch

Following the pricing announcements on Apple Watch, it seems that the "Watch" edition is priced 200$ above "Watch Sport" ($349 vs $549 for the 38mm model).

I can read the spec sheet but apart from different band options and another type of front glass and don't understand the differences.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of luxury item pricing :-)

Comment: Likewise, what are the features of the Apple Watch Edition that make it worth the extra $9500? Hint: it's not the value of the gold. ;)

Comment: I've removed the pricing focus here. Let's move that discussion to [chat] since justification of price is so subjective as to run this off-track.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to the aluminium vs stainless steel case, The Apple Watch has a [Sapphire crystal](http://www.apple.com/watch/apple-watch/stainless-steel-case-bright-blue-leather-loop/) cover as opposed to the Apple Watch Sport's ["Ion-X Glass"](http://www.apple.com/watch/apple-watch-sport/silver-aluminum-case-blue-sport-band/) cover.

[image: Apple marketing of watches]

In addition, there are more options for bands that can be used with Apple Watch. Specifically, while the [Apple Watch Sport](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-watch/apple-watch-sport) *is sold* just with the Sport band, the [Apple Watch](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-watch/apple-watch) is available with the Sport Band, the Classic Buckle, the Milanese Loop, the Leather Loop, the Link Bracelet, and the Modern Buckle.

**However**, you can purchase any band to go with your watch as every band will fit every watch. In effect, you can get the Apple Watch Sport model and then purchase the Milanese Loop to wear with it. Changing bands on all models is easy.

Comment: Can the other bands be used with the Sport? For example, can I get the Leather Loop or Milanese Loop and replace the sport band on my Sport?

Comment: All bands for a given case size (38mm vs 42mm) are usable with any model of that size, regardless of collection. Caveat: some bands are exclusive to a specific model and cannot be purchased separately (the gold bands come to mind, but also the Space Black Link Bracelet). There are other minor differences like the packaging that each collection ships with. The Edition boxes include a built-in charger and are made of high-quality leather, whereas the Sport boxes are oblong rather than square.

Comment: So are they identical "on the inside"? Battery life etc?

Comment: @Floris, yes, my understanding is that they have identical internals, although, slight variations would be possible.

Answer (score 6):

The Watch Sport is made of aluminium and glass and plastic composite backing.

The Watch is made of stainless steel, sapphire and ceramic backing.

The bands are different but those are priced as accessories and the materials there are pretty straightforward to deduce.